# jQuery window hiding

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jQuery and I wanted to ask a question. Basically I have four links that when clicked fade in a div with a jQuery function. What I would like to do is create a function so that when you click on one link all other divs fade out. So when I click on a link to fade in a div any other div whether it is one, two or three will fade out and open up the new div.

How would I do this???

Thanks!

J Winton

Comment: Sounds pretty simple.  Can you provide some sample html?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier to answer with more specifics, but let's assume your divs are differentiated by id. Furthermore, let's assume the links point to a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) that gives the id of the div you wish to *fade in*

```
$(something).click(function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('href').split("#")[1], // edit: removed the incorrect argument.
        $divs = $("div[id]"); // all divs with ids

    $divs.not("#"+target).fadeOut(); // Fade out other divs
    $divs.filter("#"+target).fadeIn(); // Fade in targeted div
});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I currently don't have any code to show you, but I'll do my best to explain it better.

What I'd like it to do is this. I'll have an unordered list with a few list items, all with id's. I'd like it to work so that when I click on one list item, it will fade in the div it is associated with in the js, and will fade out, or whatever js effect is applied, any other div that might be up. Does that make more sense? Here is an example from another website that I got the inspiration from. http://worldofmerix.com

Comment: I think you've got it backwards. The unordered list should contain anchors with links that target the ids. The *divs* you target actually have the ids. That is how worldofmerix does it, and that is how the above code does it as well. It makes the most sense, as it is how browsers actually work, even without JavaScript. Is there something in the above code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Ok @kojiro, I misunderstood that! You've been great!